# If USB 2.0 max speed is 35MBp/s (480 mbits) why am I transferring at 120MB over gigabit?

Tags: usb, external-hard-drive, gigabit-ethernet

I have a USB 2.0 External HDD and when I transfer something to/from the HDD over a gigabit network, I have a 120MB transfer speed, but USB 2.0 over supports 35MB

Comment: the Operating systems often cache data in the RAM before writing them to the Disk. This may cause that you thing the write speed is high.

Comment: Likely whats happening is the transfer rate you are reading isn't actually what is being transferred, rather, it is the maximum that can be transferred at all. Your drive cant support 120MB/s, so it only transfers 35MB/s, but if the device COULD transfer 120M/s, it would. Its like how my computer can have a 100MB/s Internet connection, but my modem only supports 25MB/s, so I only get 25MB/s.

Comment: no @BenFranchuk if it says its transferring at 120MB it's actually doing so. I agree with magicandre1981 . caching until it can write to disk

Comment: @PsychoData The cache is not infinite, so Joe just needs to do a longer transfer to see if the performance drops.

Comment: @Joe: Out of curiosity, where are you seeing this performance? You mention transferring something over a Gigabit network, but then talk about USB 2.0's limit of 35mb/s. I'm a bit confused about the exact chain of events...where does the Gigabit network come into play?

Comment: As a side note to the above, if you are transferring information over a network, it is possible that whatever you are transferring is being compressed on the wire. So, while your total data transfer may be 120mb/s, the physical transfer rate may not actually be exceeding 35mb/s...caching or no.

Comment: Lets say I transfer a 4GB file, the transfer speed will be 120GBp/s but 60% through it will drop to 35MB, which is what is expected.

HOWEVER if there are multiple files in the folder it will fluctuate, when it ends one file and starts another

Comment: Are you saying that you are transferring files that are on a USB drive to another computer on your local network? 120MB/s sounds like you are transferring a local file (as opposed to being on your external disk). USB 2 cannot reach that speed. USB 3 can, so perhaps you have a brand new hard drive and a USB 3 capable computer.

Comment: @joe Where are you reading that speed from? That could help in formulating an answer.

Comment: @Max, no its definitely USB 2.0, the server I am transferring it from (which I built) is an old Pentium D laptop running Linux. I am using Windows 8 and SMB protocol to transfer to and from, and windows 8 tells me (graphically) 120MBp/s

Comment: Could this be Megabits/sec instead of Megabytes/sec? That would be 15Megabytes/sec, which would correspond to USB 2. And you say you see this "graphically", you mean in the Activity Monitor?

Comment: No its Megabytes because it transfer 1 gb in less than 20 seconds

Comment: Well 1Gbps is 119MBps, so it is definitely being transfered at the maximum speed of the network. If it is indeed a USB 2.0 drive, then the notion of cache seems to be the likeliest explanation. If it is a USB HDD, then unlike a USB flash-drive, it is probably set to optimized-for-speed as opposed to optimize-for-quick-removal, which means that Windows does indeed use caching. That said, it would help to know the size of the file(s) being transferred and the amount of (free) RAM since those would affect the cache.